# Figure de style imbriquées

Tags: figure-de-style

Bonjour,

Dans une histoire pour enfants, nous sommes tombés sur le passage suivant :

"Tout d'un coup, les vagues se firent plus grosses, et, là-bas ! sur la gauche ! Une vague, comme trois fois son bateau ; crac! ..."

Comment peut-on appeler ce style très oral pour embarquer le lecteur dans l'action ?
Ainsi que le figure finale qui consiste à ne pas finir sa phrase ?

Merci!

-- EDIT : typo

Comment: Peut-être un lien utile : https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/les-figures-de-style-f1349

Comment: Je ne suis pas spécialiste mais je dirais qu'il s'agit d'une gradation : https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/la-gradation-f1363

Comment: Are you sure it was "les vagues *de* firent ..." and not "les vagues *se* firent ..."?

Comment: Merci Tsundoku, c'est corrigé.

Answer (score 3):

Ce style très oral pour embarquer le lecteur dans l'action s'appelle... "un style très oral, pour embarquer le lecteur dans l'action". Du point de vue des figures de style, on relève une gradation, l'introduction d'onomatopées. Quant à la figure de style finale, consistant à ne pas finir la phrase, elle porte le nom barbare d'[aposiopèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposiop%C3%A8se).